# Cannot query across many-to-many for property subject typeorm with nestjs

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am getting one error with typerom and postgreesql- `Cannot query across many-to-many for property subject` when I try to update my entity. I am not understanding where is the problem. Please help me someone!

Here is my entity-

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, ManyToMany, UpdateDateColumn, CreateDateColumn, JoinTable } from "typeorm";
//Orm Entity
import { User } from "src/user/model/user.entity";
import { Class } from "src/classes/model/class.entity";
import { Subject } from "src/subject/model/subject.entity";
@Entity()
export class Student {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;
    @ManyToOne(() => Class)
    class: Class;
    @ManyToMany(() => Subject, { cascade: true })
    @JoinTable()
    subject: Subject[];
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    studentId: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    name: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    image: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    gender: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    dob: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    blood: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    religion: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    number: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    email: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    date: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    birthCertificate: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    fatherName: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    fatherNidNumber: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    fatherPhone: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    motherName: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    motherNidNumber: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    motherPhone: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    guardianName: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    guardianNidNumber: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    guardianPhone: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    address: string;
    @Column({ type: "text" })
    school: string;
    @ManyToOne(() => User)
    createdBy: User;
    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamptz" })
    updated_at: Date;
    @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamptz" })
    created_at: Date;
}
```

And I am getting error when I try to update studentEntity-

```
async update(studentInput: StudentInput, id: string, reqUser: ReqUser) {
        const subjects: Subject[] = await Promise.all(
            studentInput.subject.map((id: string) => this.subjectRepository.findOneBy({ id: id }))
        );
        const result = await this.studentRepository.update(id, {
            ...studentInput,
            class: { id: studentInput.class },
            createdBy: { id: reqUser.id },
            subject: subjects
        });
        if (result.affected === 0) throw new NotFoundException("Student not found!");
        return {
            success: true,
            message: "Student updated successfully!"
        }
    };
```

I create successfully by this way. But when I try to update my student, I am getting the error.
Here I am building my project with nestjs

//Edited

```
[Nest] 13464  - 03/17/2023, 6:41:36 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot query across many-to-many for property subject
Error: Cannot query across many-to-many for property subject
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.createPropertyPath (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\src\query-builder\QueryBuilder.ts:1367:27)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.createUpdateExpression (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\src\query-builder\UpdateQueryBuilder.ts:493:18)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.getQuery (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\src\query-builder\UpdateQueryBuilder.ts:53:21)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.getQueryAndParameters (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\src\query-builder\QueryBuilder.ts:507:28)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.execute (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\src\query-builder\UpdateQueryBuilder.ts:142:50)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at StudentService.update (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\src\student\student.service.ts:107:24)
    at target (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\node_modules\@nestjs\core\helpers\external-context-creator.js:74:28)
    at Object.updateStudent (G:\Web Devlopment\E-Campus\server\node_modules\@nestjs\core\helpers\external-proxy.js:9:24)
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the complete error message you are getting, as text - **no images**.

Comment: I update my question with the complete error message.

Comment: @Belayer, Hello